# Matching on part of a string in a unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following test:

```
self.assertDictEquals(
  result,
  {
     1: 2,
     3: 4,
     5: "Error: You entered 1, while one of the following values was expected: 2, 3, ... 1000"    
  }
)
```

where the string above is very long as it lists all the expected values. Therefore I wish to only confirm that the start of this string is as expected. I could do it like this:

```
assert len(result) == 3
assert result[1] == 2
assert result[3] == 4
assert result[5].startswith("Error: You entered 1, while one of the following values was expected:")
```

But I prefer this as this is a recurring issue:

```
class CONTAINING:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    
    def __eq__(self, container)
        return self.v in container

self.assertDictEquals(
  result,
  {
     1: "2",
     3: "4",
     5: CONTAINING("Error: You entered 1, while one of the following values was expected:")    
  }
)
```

Is there any other way to do this using the unittest framework in python?

Comment: I think that your solution is perfect. In the test there is a mistake: the method of unittest.TestCase is `assertDictEqual()` and not `assertDictEquals()`.

Comment: how about something like: `assert result.pop(5).startswith("Error") and result == {1:"2", 3:"4"}`?

Comment: Also, why delete your mostly identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77240732/1358308?